# Is middleware reserved subdir for Nodejs/express app?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a few dumb question about middleware. I understand that middleware function in nodejs takes `req, res` and pass to `next` at the end for next function to be executed. The middleware runs at app, router, error handling and 3rd party.

1. is the `middleware` for `exprss` ONLY?  Or it is common for any `nodejs` app.
2. is the `middleware` subdir reserved for every nodejs or express app?
3. Also is every file under `middleware` subdir automatically picked up and executed by the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, and no. There are other frameworks that use the concept of middleware, but I wouldn't call it common.
2. No, a subdirectory called `middleware` is not in any way treated special by Node.js *or* Express. There might be frameworks that *use* Express which assign a special meaning to that subdirectory, but it would be special only for that framework.
3. No, but see 2 (some frameworks *might* work that way).

Answer (score 1):

Middlewares are not just in ExpressJS or a reserved key in NodeJS or folder structure. It's a hook in the HTTP request and response lifecycle. Most of the popular web frameworks includes this concept in it's design not just ExpressJS or NodeJS as a JS engine, you can have a look at some of them

ExpressJS

> Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next middleware function is commonly denoted by a variable named next. [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Django (Python web framework):

> Middleware is a framework of hooks into Django’s request/response processing. It’s a light, low-level “plugin” system for globally altering Django’s input or output. [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/)

Laravel (PHP web framework):

> Middleware provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering your application. For example, Laravel includes a middleware that verifies the user of your application is authenticated. If the user is not authenticated, the middleware will redirect the user to the login screen. However, if the user is authenticated, the middleware will allow the request to proceed further into the application. [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware)